# Swiftmailer Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP.............with message "535 Authentication Failed "

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, zoho

I'm using ZOHO mail in order to sender from swiftmailer. I must say that with gmail account as smtp sender works without any problem:

From the .env file i'm using the following format:

MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.zoho.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=no-reply@domain.com&password=password

I tried also with SSL and using the following format too:

smtp://user:pass@host:port/?timeout=60&encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&

I tried also the "application mode" from zoho in order to grant access through the application password but the result is the same.

Anyone has been worked with zoho as smtp sender?

Thanks

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with zoho support.

The problem was related with the smtp.zoho.com.

My account was in EU servers. Just using the smtp.zoho.eu works like a charm.

Kind regards.